# Issue with a walk target in unity c# Vr

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I am making a game where I am trying to get Ethan (AIThirdPersonController) to walk to where ever the user is.  The user moves by looking where they want to go and then start and stops with a button click.
the code I wrote for ethan to go to wherever the user is is this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class LookMoveTo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject MeMyselfEye;
    void Update()
{
        transform.position = MeMyselfEye.transform.position;

    }
}
```

with MeMyselfEye being the game object that holds the main camera and the character controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack)
this is an image of my MeMyselfEye game object
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue2yu.jpg)
This is an image of my walkTarget game object which holds the LookMoveTo script.
If anyone knows how to get Ethan to follow/walk to wherever the player in the vr headset is plaese let me know, Thanks!

These are the images for the inspector panel for ethan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11i8i.png).imgur.com/uCjFu.jpg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2vCu.png)

this is the inspector panel for MeMyselfEye
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peRVi.png)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the Ethan character does move, When run he tries to go to a specific point and then just stopes there.  No matter where I move him it is always that one point even though the MeMyselfEye game object constantly moves its position as the user moves around

Comment: Could we see the inspector details for both `ethan` and `memyselfeye` perhaps?

Comment: @Jake I'll add them now

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out nothing was wrong with my code.  I made an entire new project and then just made everything exactly the same and it just worked.  Thanks to anyone who read this or spent time trying to find an answer

Comment: oh and thanks to @Jake for taking the time to comment